# Topology: Open and Closed Sets

Tags: general-topology

Topology: Why do we consider the set $(2.9,3.1)$ open whereas $[2.9,3.1)$ is not considered to be open?

My understanding of open sets is that an open set is one such that for an element $x$ in a set, we can find sort of a 'neighborhood' or distance more than $0$ (doesn't matter how small, so as long as it's more than $0$) that will still be in the set.

I understand that for $[2.9,3.1)$ if the point I select is on $2.9$ then any distance ($d$) from it would fall out of the set. But won't the same apply for the $(2.9,3.1)$ case as well? After all, $(2.9,3.1)$ spans a smaller range than $[2.9,3.1)$, so it stands to reason that if a point $2.9$ falls out of $[2.9,3.1)$, it will fall out of $(2.9, 3.1)$ as well.

Comment: We don't. $\qquad$

Comment: Your latter set is neither closed nor open.  (In the usual topology)

Comment: I'd suppose my phrasing wasn't very accurate. When I said [2.9,3.1) was closed, I actually meant 'not open'.

Comment: It would be instructive for you to write down a proof yourself for why one is open but the other isnt.

Answer (score 2):

$2.9\not\in(2.9,3.1)$, so we don't run into the same problem as for $[2.9,3.1)$.  There is in fact a neighborhood $N_x$ of any $x\in (2.9,3.1)$ with $x\in N_x\subset (2.9,3.1)$.  In fact you could choose $N_x=(2.9,3.1)$...

Answer (score 2):

You look like a little bit confused on this topic.

First of all, you have to specify the topology, anyway let's assume we are using Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Second, the set $A:=[2.9,3.1)$ is not closed in this topology:

- It is not open: because you cannot find any open ball centered in $2.9$ contained in $A$.
- It is not closed: a set is closed if and only if his complementary is open, and it's complementary is $C:=(-\infty,2.9)\cup[3.1,+\infty)$, which is not open because you cannot find any open ball centered in $3.1$ contained in $C$.

About your second sentence: $2.9 \notin (2.9,3.1)$, so you don't have to check it.

Comment: Hi, I'm learning this topic. May I ask why one has to specify the topology? What other kinds of topology other than the Euclidean topology are there?

Comment: Many options. For example the topology where every subset is open, or the topology where a set is open if and only if it is $\mathbf{R}\setminus S$ where $S$ is a finite subset of $\mathbf{R}$. There is also a topology generated by half-open intervals rather than open intervals

Comment: As Sam said, there can be lots of topologies. You can even order some of them by inclusion of the open sets. For example you can always define the trivial topology (open sets are empty set and all the space) and the discrete topology (open sets are all the possible subsets).

Comment: The topology measures how much you can distinguish stuff in your space. More and smaller are your open sets, more you can see and distinguish in your space.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the definition of topological space - in which is defined what a open set is - and apply definition to your case (the other answers are the application of the definitions).